# Run function again only after it has been completed

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I'm trying to make a program that adds text to a web-page, like so:

```
Hello
Morning
Morning
Morning
Morning
Evening
```

There should be:

1. 5 second delay between "Hello" and the first "Morning".
2. 5 second delay between each "Morning".
3. 6 second delay between the last "Morning" and "Evening".

Here's the whole HTML and JavaScript I've got so far.

```js
function notify(msg, loops, taskTime) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("notifications");
  for (let i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var li = document.createElement("li")
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${msg}`));
        ul.appendChild(li)
      }, taskTime * i)
    }(i))
  }
}

notify('Hello', 1, 5000)
notify('Morning', 4, 5000)
notify('Evening', 1, 6000)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="notifications" style="list-style-type:none;margin-left:10%;"></ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that on loading the web-page, the output is:

```
Hello
Morning
Evening
Morning
Morning
Morning
```

How can I make sure that the function is ran in the order I want it to and not this mixed output? The first 3 outputs also appear instantly instead of a delay. How do I avoid that?

Comment: You're _scheduling_ six timeouts all at the same time. If you want them to occur in sequence, use a task queue (e.g. an array) with "what to do, after how many milliseconds" elements, and use a queue handling function that exits is the queue is empty, and if not, shifts out an element, schedules its timeout, and adds some extra code that calls itself once that run completes as part of what to run in the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the number of miliseconds so the setTimeout that comes after has the correct time assigned. Also, you was multiplying the `taskTime` and `i`, which was always 0. I replaced `i` with `i + 1` instead.

Just try this JavaScript code instead (it works):

```
function notify(msg, loops, taskTime) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("notifications");
  for (let i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        var li = document.createElement("li")
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${msg}`));
        ul.appendChild(li)
      }, taskTime * (i + 1))
    }(i))
  }
}

notify('Hello', 1, 5000)
notify('Morning', 4, 5000 * 2)
notify('Evening', 1, 6000 + 5000 * 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike's comment:

```
tasks = [
    {message: 'Hello', delay: 5000},
    {message: 'Morning', delay: 5000},
    {message: 'Morning', delay: 5000},
    {message: 'Morning', delay: 5000},
    {message: 'Morning', delay: 5000},
    {message: 'Evening', delay: 6000},
]

function runTask(index) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("notifications");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${tasks[index].message}`));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if(index < tasks.length - 1){
        setTimeout( () => runTask(index + 1), tasks[index].delay);
    }
}

if(tasks.length > 0) runTask(0); //make sure the task list has at least one element.
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for your code. Code dumps are rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JavaScript, `async` functions should probably be your first port of call when writing async code. They are clearer and usually easier to understand.

In the following, `delay` promisifies `setTimeout`.

`notify` adds `li` elements to the document in a loop, with a delay added at the beginning of each iteration.

I am unsure if this behaves as you need for the first `"Hello"`.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms))
const ul = document.getElementById("notifications")

async function notify(msg, count, ms) {       
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      await delay(ms)
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = `${msg} ${Date()}`
      ul.appendChild(li)
    }
}

(async () => {
    await notify('Hello', 1, 5000)
    await notify('Morning', 4, 5000)
    await notify('Evening', 1, 6000)
})()
```

```html
<p>Notifications will appear below:</p>
<ul id="notifications"></ul>
```